# lucene index updating strategy

Tags: lucene

I'm working on building lucene web server (in Java) for my application and expecting almost 100 search hits/second by upstream application to this server (this server will be hosted on various physical boxes which is balanced by a load balancer).

Data perspective I will be having almost 50K documents (each document less than 1kb size) and daily having new/updated ~500 documents.

I would like to know most recommended way to build indexes on 500 documents daily without impacting performance on upstream scan process.

I cannot use any shared location between all my servers for file index sharing, couple of options I can think of

1) use DB indexes (JDBC Directory) - not sure on PROs and CONs
2) use RAMDirectory indexes - not sure on update strategy.
3) use file indexes - cannot think of robust design to build and circulate file base indexes between various physical boxes.

Would like to know thoughts/recommendations on correct index setup strategy.

Comment: What latency of updates showing up in the query results is acceptable?

Comment: We are flexible in latency - we should be good for hour or little more (as mentioned we will be updating data once a day, maybe after update of data we want to start using the data in an hour or so)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really need to build the Query/Indexing server by yourself?

Have you considered [ElasticSearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/)? It will partition and replicate your index automatically, you just need to configure how many partition you want and how many replicas for each partition. It will also give you a simple HTTP interface to index and query. In ElasticSearch all nodes/instances are equal so you can send and query documents to any of the nodes.

With an index as small as 50K I guess a single partition with a few replicas would handle your 100 queries/second requirement.

Anyway it seems that your requirements are light. 50K documents with less that 1KB seems like a good fit for an in-memory index (RAMDirectory in lucene). Depending on the queries that will be issued to the index you could have less machines handle the 100 queries/second.

The indexing of new documents can be done in a lot of ways, considering that you don't have hard requirements on the update latency and the number of new documents is very small. You could send the documents via HTTP to each instance, send via ssh/ftp a CSV file (or something else) with the updated documents, and once a day each instance index this file.

Comment: Thanks Felipe, I might not able to use ElasticSearch as from my search java service I wanted to perform some other minor tasks too which I want to combine with this.  For your later suggestion, I can send documents to box but how my RAMDirectory object will be updated automatically ? As I mentioned I dont want any performance impact on search operation...

Comment: You can index to the RAMDirectory and to a FSDirectory (file system storage) at the same time. At instance startup you open up the FSDirectory and then open a RAMDirectory passing the FSDirectory as parameter. That way you get a in-memory index and a in-file index.

Comment: Sure, but I dont have luxury to start instance everyday after index update.

Comment: You don't have to. The part when I say "start instance" is just in case an instance goes down or something. Normally, you just need to index both on the RAMDirectory and on the FSDirectory. Or you could just index on the FSDirectory and get a RAMDirectory from it at the end of indexing.